# How to stop a function before it finishes in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout, setinterval

I have a program where when you click a button, a series of 5 lights and sounds play on a loop (basically, certain cells in the tables background colour change in order). I have another button "cancel" which cancels it. However, when you click cancel, it still finishes the current loop its on. Ideally I want it to stop mid loop and reset everything to how it is at the start (or at the end).

Here is my javaScript..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var note1 = new Audio("audio/1.wav");
var note2 = new Audio("audio/2.wav");
var note3 = new Audio("audio/3.wav");
var note4 = new Audio("audio/4.wav");
var note5 = new Audio("audio/5.wav");

var isPlaying = false;
var speed = 500;
var buttonPressed = false;

var interval;

$("#button1").click(function(){
    if (!buttonPressed) {
        noteLoop();
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(noteLoop, 5000);
        $("#button1").text("MAKING CONTACT");
    };

$("#button2").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $("#button1").text("CLICK TO MAKE CONTACT");
    buttonPressed = false;
    $.finish();
})

});

var noteLoop = function() {
    if (!isPlaying){
        playNotes();
        };
    }

var playNotes = function() {
        setTimeout(play1, speed);
        setTimeout(play2, speed * 2);
        setTimeout(play3, speed * 3);   
        setTimeout(play4, speed * 4.6);
        setTimeout(play5, speed * 6.2);
        setTimeout(function(){
            resetNotes();
            isPlaying = false;
        }, speed * 9); 
};

var play1 = function() {
    isPlaying = true;
    $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").addClass("yellow");
    $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").hide();
    $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").fadeIn('fast');
    note1.play();
};

var play2 = function() {
    $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("yellow");
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)").addClass("green");
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)").hide();
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)").fadeIn('fast');
    note2.play();
};

var play3 = function() {
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)").removeClass("green");
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)").addClass("blue");
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)").hide();
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)").fadeIn('fast');
    note3.play();
};

var play4 = function() {
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)").removeClass("blue");
    $("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)").addClass("white");
    $("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)").hide();
    $("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)").fadeIn('fast');
    note4.play();
};

var play5 = function() {
    $("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("white");
    $("table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)").addClass("orange");
    $("table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)").hide();
    $("table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)").fadeIn('fast');
    note5.play();
};

var resetNotes = function() {
    $("table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("orange");
};
```

});

I'm also aware that I may have gone about this thing entirely the wrong way and what I want to do might not even be possible. I also wanted it to get faster and faster every time it looped but I couldn't figure out any way to make that possible :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: According to your code (If you are working with audio/video) you could add event listener named "timeupdate"  to an audio element and check inside its handler for any cancellation requested if so restart your loop again .. let me know if it is not clear to give you an example.

Comment: Sorry I am still pretty new to this so if you could give an example that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code excerpt, you could add event listener named "timeupdate"  to an audio element and check inside its handler for any cancellation requested if so restart your loop again .. below is an excerpt code  "I did not test :( but it just simplifies the idea for you"

```
<html>
<body>
  <audio id="myAudio"></audio>
  <button id="button1">Start</button>
  <button id="button2">Cancel</button>

  <script>
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    //keep your notes in array 
    var audios = ["audio/1.wav", "audio/2.wav", ...];
    var isCancelled = false;
    var currentTrack = null;

    myAudio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
        if(isCancelled){
            //reset here .. do your stuff here according to current track 
            myAudio.pause();
        }
    });

    function noteLoop(){
        for (i = 0;i<audios.length; i++){
            currentTrack = audios[i];
            play(audios[i]);
        }
    }

    function play(track){
        if(track){
            //do your stuff here according to track 
            $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").addClass("yellow");
            $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").hide();
            $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").fadeIn('fast');
            myAudio.play();
        }
    }

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        isCancelled = false;
        noteLoop();
        $("#button1").text("MAKING CONTACT");
    });

    $("#button2").click(function() {
        isCancelled = true;
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```